# Is it possible to use Content Bloom Alchemy plugin framework with Tridion 9.1x?

Tags: a4t

Officially, Content Bloom's Alchemy for Tridion (A4T) framework is currently supported up to Web 8.5, but is there a way to install and use it with Tridion 9.1x?

Answer (score 5):

The following are the pretty straight forward steps I followed to get Alchemy installed on a Tridion 9.1.1966 environment:

WARNING BLURB: As always, take care when modifying your windows registry settings by hand.  I would recommend backing up your current registry unless you are completely comfortable with editing it yourself.  Remember, you accept any ramifications of making any modifications to your registry

1. Download Alchemy4Tridion-v1.0.1.1.msi
2. With Registy Editor (regedit.exe), navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Tridion\Content Manager
3. Record value of Version KEY (for example: "9.1.1966")
4. Modify value of Version KEY to "8.5"
5. Install Alchemy using msi (wait until completed)
6. Modify value of Version KEY back to value recorded is step 3 (for example: "9.1.1966")
7. Enjoy your Tridion 9.x with Alchemy!

Credit goes to Dave Whiting for the research and hacking to get it to work.

Comment: Great! 
In case someone don't want to touch registries in DTAP environments.
1. Do it on a Tridion 9.x Sandbox. 
2. Test a plugin on the sandbox.
3. Get the deployed source from the sandbox.
4. Deploy it manually to upper environments. 

*This might need some updates to the code.